# Converting an array to replicate an associative/sequential json

Tags: php, arrays, json

I'm trying to replicate this json by converting a php array with `json_encode`:

```
"sort" : [
    { "age" : "desc" },
    "_score"
]
```

With the following PHP array:

```
$json_doc['sort'] = array(
    "_score",
    "age"=>"desc"
);
```

If I just have the score in the array, PHP properly does not assign a key to the array:

```
"sort" : [
    "_score"
]
```

But when I mix the `"age"=>"desc"` into the mix, `json_encode` does not encode the `_score` correctly:

```
"sort": {
    "0": "_score",
    "age": "desc"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$json_doc['sort'] = Array(
      "_score",
      Array('age' => 'desc')
    );
```